# Redactor field and bootstrap's modal window (on django)

Tags: jquery, django, twitter-bootstrap, redactor

Using django 1.8.3, bootstrap 3.3.4, jquery 2.1.1 and django-wysiwyg-redactor 0.4.9;  I'm trying to dynamically render a modal windows with a form in it. The form is generated by an ajax request. To enable the redactor on the textarea field in the form I just run the .redactor() and everything is fine.

If the form has errors, I have to change the .modal-body content and when I do it, I run again the .redactor() but in some fields the toolbar is visible and in other is not visible or visible but misplaced in the textarea. (at the bottom or in the middle of the textarea)

I tried so far and without any success:

- the .redactor('core.destroy') and than redactor()
- to refresh (hide() and show()) the toolbar for every textfield

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in redactor but in the modal. I don't know if is the version of bootstrap but at the moment I solved in this way:

I create a couple functions to enable and disable the redactor fields. In the modal window, if the ajax get an error I do:

```
// maybe is not necessary buy I prefer to disable the fields
disableRedactor(fields);

// fill the response in the modal
$(modal).find('.modal-body').html(response);

// scroll the modal to the top
$(modal).scrollTop(0);

// enable the new fields
enableRedactor($('#consultant-form textarea'));
```

The function to enable the redactor fields are:

```
var enableRedactor = function(fields){
    _.each($(fields), function(field){
        $(field).redactor();
    });
};

var disableRedactor = function(fields){
    _.each($(fields), function(field){
        $(field).redactor('core.destroy');
    });
};
```